# Receiving Android Riskware smsreg when trying to send text from app

Tags: android, sms

First off I am new to programming and right now I am just trying to run through some tutorials using Android Studio.

I have created a sample button and I thought I would look ahead and trying to have that button send a text message.

I have added the permission 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />` to the manifest file.

In adding the permission above to the manifest and try to run the app using my phone I receipt an Antivirus warning that it's detected Android Riskware smsreg and it get quarantined.

Is this normal behavior or is there something else I need to do?

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(message);

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("xxxxxxxxxx", null, message, null, null);
}
```

}

Manifest file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

</application>
```

Screenshot:
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N58zC.png)

Thanks

Comment: first thing you need to do is share the exception, consider add images & code so we can reproduce this issue

Comment: @iddoE just updated question with code - sorry!

Comment: all good, can you add screen shot for the exception ?

Comment: @iddoE - ok just updated with screenshot - hope this helps! thanks again for taking a look at this.

Comment: one additional thing here is that if I remove the uses permissions from the manifest file then it builds just fine but when I click the button i created the app crashes